# Using Faker to get and set gender for all following data

Tags: node.js, typescript, faker.js

I'm using [Faker](https://fakerjs.dev/) with TypeScript and am struggling to figure out how to capture the returned gender from Faker in a way that I can then use in subsequent calls. This is what I'd like to do:

```
const gender = faker.name.gender(true);  // <-- returns a string
const firstName = faker.name.firstName(gender);  
const middleName = faker.name.middleName(gender);
```

Unfortunately, Faker's `faker.name.firstName(gender)` takes a `GenderType` enum value, not a string, even though you can use it like `faker.name.firstName('male')`. That works, but using the variable `gender` doesn't work.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The problem is that firstName only accepts 'male' or 'female', **not** any string, but gender can return any string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`faker.name.firstName`](https://fakerjs.dev/api/name.html#firstName) has the type `(gender?: GenderType) => string`, where `type GenderType = 'female' | 'male' | 0 | 1;`*.

However, [`faker.name.gender`](https://fakerjs.dev/api/name.html#gender) has the type `(binary?: boolean = false) => string`. It can return quite a broad range of values:

```
> faker.name.gender()
'T* woman'
> faker.name.gender()
'Intersex'
> faker.name.gender()
'Cis'
```

Unhelpfully, even if you set `binary` to `true`, what it returns is `"Female"` or `"Male"`, neither of which is actually a `GenderType`:

```
> faker.name.gender(true)
'Male'
> faker.name.gender(true)
'Female'
```

although there is some normalisation, so this works in JavaScript (but **not** TypeScript):

```
> faker.name.firstName("Male")
'Ilene'
```

---

To make this work you'd have to add some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), for example:

```
import { faker, GenderType } from "@faker-js/faker";
const gender = faker.name.gender(true).toLowerCase() as GenderType;
                                                  // ^ we know this will be true
const name = faker.name.firstName(gender);
```

or, if you want to work with the capitalised version, using the [intrinisic string manipulation types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#lowercasestringtype):

```
const gender = faker.name.gender(true) as "Female" | "Male";
                                    // ^ we know this will be true

// ...

const name = faker.name.firstName(gender.toLowerCase() as Lowercase<typeof gender>);
                                                    // ^ this is obviously true
                                                    //   (if ugly...)
```

These seem awkward enough that I've opened [a bug](https://github.com/faker-js/faker/issues/776) to explore whether it can be fixed upstream.

*(Also it looks like the string case typing is [being explored](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44268) in TypeScript, so maybe the `as Lowercase` won't be needed at some point.)*

---

* *The numerical values are deprecated:*

```
> faker.name.firstName(0)
[@faker-js/faker]: name.firstName(number) is deprecated since v6.1.0 and will be removed in v7.0.0. Please use 'female' or 'male' instead.
'Forrest'
```

Comment: This is all great information!  Something that might be worth adding to the bug you created is adding the gender option for the suffix data.  Often the data generates a female name but then due to lack of a gender filter will return a "III", or "Jr.",  etc... rendering a name like, "Ms. Jenny Maria Wilson Jr."  While this isn't technically a bug it would help to create more consistent data.  Just my two cents.

Comment: @JamesFranken I'd suggest you comment on the bug directly, I'm not actually using this functionality so can't speak to the details.

Answer (score 0):

For a Python Implementation, I used:

```
from faker import Faker
a = Faker()
print(a.name_female())
```